# Can't save record attributes to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, persistence

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :email
  def initialize(data)
    data.each { |k, v| send("#{k}=", v) }
  end
end
```

In rails console

```
Contact.create!({"email"=>"foo@gmail.com"})
```

The record saved to the database has `email` as nil

Update:
The data is being passed in is JSON. I am getting all the data from the JSON and trying to save that into the database.

Comment: I dont know if it matters but I always use symbols for these hashes  email: 'foo@gmail.com'

Comment: The data being passed in is JSON data

Comment: did you try `.to_hash` on the JSON data?

Comment: Just tried and didn't have an effect

Comment: How about `Contact.create!( email: data.to_hash['email'] )`

Comment: The issue comes because data does not only pass in the email attribute. Data has many attributes within it, so creating a Contact record from this way would be alittle verbose.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy The Contact.create!( email: data.to_hash['email'] ), but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

Contact.create!(email: "foo@gmail.com")

The email as a `:symbol` and no curly brackets?

Also, why are you initializing in your model?

Comment: What do you mean why am I initializing in the model? I'm pulling attributes from the data hash in order to make they actual attributes. I believe once I create an instance variable with the attribute I want saved to the the db, then I can access those attributes later.

Comment: `Contact.new` initializes an instance of `Contact`, and you can pass data through it too.

Answer (score 1):

With `Mohamed El Mahallaway`, I think your code setup could be improved (to negate initializing your model). I think you'll be better using the [`strong_params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) functionality of Rails:

```
#app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb
def new 
    @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.email = "foo@gmail.com"
    @contact.save
end

private

def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:email, :other, :params)
end
```

I may have miscalculated your competency with Rails, but this is the "Rails" way to save the correct data to your model :) You may to have a `before_save` method in your model to use the `email` attribute, considering it's a virtual attribute